# PHP print array in other pages for use over multiple pages

Tags: php, arrays, include, file-put-contents

I need an array in multiple pages, so I tried to make a php file where the array is printed. I used:

```
file_put_contents('file.php',
    '<?php $order = ' . var_export($order1, true) . '; ?>');
```

I was hoping that if I included this file in the files where I need the array, I could use it as `$order`, but I get an error instead.
I checked `file.php` and everything looks in order.
Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create `.php` files by your backend. It is not secure.
I recommend you to use JSON for that:

```
      file_put_contents('file.json',json_encode($order1));
      $order = json_decode(file_get_content($url), true);
```

And you should hide this files from web in your .htaccess or by another available method for secure purpose.

Comment: array `$order1` is a multidimensional array containing objects, is it possible that the objects become arrays after the decode? Because I can't recall `$idA = $order1[$Q][0]->id;` anymore.

Comment: `$order = json_decode(file_get_content($url), false);` but everything will be an object (last parametr in json_decode goes to false)

Comment: Also you can use "serialize" not the `json_decode`:  `file_put_contents('file.json', serialize($order1));  $order = unserialize(file_get_content($url));`